# datatables using mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I am fairly new to php and extremely new to anything involving javascript.

I am trying to use a datatable to display the results of a mysql query.

below is the first file, which i called snoozetable.php (please don't ask me about the ridiculous name).

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'id', 'side', 'blockType', 'Partner', 'locPattern', 'locName', 'snoozelocType', 'reference', 'dpid', 'match_exp', 'description', 'unblockdescription', 'snoozedate', 'unsnoozeDate', 'deletedate' );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "snoozes";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "username";
    $gaSql['password']   = "pass1";
    $gaSql['db']         = "dbname";
    $gaSql['server']     = "servername";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }


    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

from what i can tell, that php part of this is fine, though if i try to run just that file, the page times out.

i am calling that one from a second file using the below header:

```
<head>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script class="init" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../tools/ajax/snoozetable.php"
/*        "aoColumns": [
                mData: 'SnoozeID'
                mData: 'Side'
                mData: 'BlockType'
                mData: 'Partner'
                mData: 'Pattern'
                mData: 'Location'
                mData: 'SnoozeOn'
                mData: 'Reference/Description'
                mData: 'DP'
                mData: 'fullBlock'
                mData: 'Reason to Snooze'
                mData: 'Reason to Unsnooze'
                mData: 'Snooze'
                mData: 'Unsnooze'
                mData: 'Delete'
                ]
*/  } );
} );
</script>
</head>
```

and then later in the same file I have :

```
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SnoozeID</th>
                <th>Side</th>
                <th>BlockType</th>
                <th>Partner</th>
                <th>Pattern</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>SnoozeOn</th>
                <th>Reference/Description</th>
                <th>DP</th>
                <th>fullBlock</th>
                <th>Reason to Snooze</th>
                <th>Reason to Unsnooze</th>
                <th>Snooze</th>
                <th>Unsnooze</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>SnoozeID</th>
                <th>Side</th>
                <th>BlockType</th>
                <th>Partner</th>
                <th>Pattern</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>SnoozeOn</th>
                <th>Reference/Description</th>
                <th>DP</th>
                <th>fullBlock</th>
                <th>Reason to Snooze</th>
                <th>Reason to Unsnooze</th>
                <th>Snooze</th>
                <th>Unsnooze</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: At the first sight. your javascript seems fine. Whats the problem? Are you seeing any kind of error? You need to check php_error_log and tell us. You can check your browser console if there is any javascript error or response from your AJAX call.

Comment: okay. there was a db connection issue which was causing the timeout, the snoozetable.php page when viewed alone now echos the contents of table with no formatting. so that part i guess is working okay.

Comment: the issue is that all i get is the header and the footer and the table data is not outputed

Comment: i figured out the issue. there was a different script at the bottom of the code that was messing with this one.